# Django Order concated queryset

Tags: django, django-views

How can I order my concatenated querysets?
I can make a for loop and print each date

```
for r in requests:
    print(r.game.date)
```

but I cant order the queryset.

**views.py**

```
class Games(TemplateView):
    template_name = ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)
        team = Team.objects.get(team=user)
        requests_single = Request.objects.filter(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(CustomUser)).filter(object_id=self.request.user.pk)
        requests_team = Request.objects.filter(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Team)).filter(object_id=team.pk)
        requests = requests_single | requests_team
        requests.order_by('-game.date')
        context['requests'] = request
        return context
```

**model.py**

```
class Forderung(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Spiel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double-underscore syntax to represent a join.

```
requests = requests.order_by('-game__date')
```

Answer (score 1):

`order_by` does not sort the queryset in place, it returns a new queryset. Try:

```
requests = requests.order_by('-game.date')
```